# Photoshop CC 20.0.4 - Unwanted Pixel line in Thumbnail Preview

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, windows

Since I've upgraded from PS 2017 to version 20.0.4, I'm seeing a grey 1 pixel line in the Thumbnail preview in the Layers panel - no matter which color theme and which thumbnail size I use. Is this supposed to indicate something?

[image]

Cheers
Florian

Comment: It's not the bug at all! it's just behaviour of photoshop i think because it seems visible when light theme is on and when you switch to dark theme it just becomes normal (yes it still exist but it is very hardly visible!)

Comment: Why does the *layer panel **thumbnail** preview* even matter? By definition "thumbnail" isn't mean to be a 100% accurate rendering.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's the same reason why an icon of hidden layers looks like on Windows this when zoomed in

[image]

And like this on Mac

[image]

And in CS6 the arrows of groups on Windows looked like it's a bit chipped:

[image]

And `Grid` in newest Photoshops looks like this when zoomed it:

[image]

— to make perfectionists and people with OCD go crazy.

Comment: Indeed. Ever since Adobe apps support windows UI scaling, it has been plagued with these “off-by-one-pixel” bugs. I suspect that on MacOS it’s better because MacOS handles UI scaling differently. (

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but worth an answer I think.

It's part of the user interface colour theme. It has nothing to do with anything on the actual image, or any bug.

Here is a screenshot of what the layers panel looks like in the four colour schemes, from darkest to lightest. The white line is not present in the two darker themes, but is present in the two lighter grey themes.

[image]